# How to generate html table with data for select box from existing db table? PHP&MySql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

My error is: "don't exist records for list on the table" but i have records in table.

When user like to generate a table with data for "predmeti"(subject on english), must picks with select boxes.

***Example if first select box value is "Math", in database table where column value is "Math", generate table with that row.

This is my page_to_process.php

*I`m new in php still learning. I'm student and this need for my project. 
*Sorry for my bad english. Thanks for everyone who can help me.

```
$subject1=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['predmet1']);
$subject2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['predmet2']);
$link=Conect();
$query="SELECT * FROM raspored WHERE predmet='".$subject1."'";
$action=mysql_query($query,$link) or die("Error: ".mysql_error());


if(mysql_num_rows($action) > 0)
{

?>
<table border="0">
<tr COLSPAN=2 BGCOLOR="#6D8FFF">
  <td>Name1</td>
  <td>Name2</td>
  <td>Name3</td>
</tr>
<?php     
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($action))
{
  echo "<tr>".
       "<td>".$row["ID"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$row["predmet"]."</td>".
       "<td>".$row["profesor"]."</td>".
       "</tr>";
}

}
else
{
 echo "don't exist records for list on the table";
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
</table>
```

This is my memberpage.php with form

```
<?php session_start(); 
require('includes/config.php'); 

//пренасочи ако корисникот не е логиран
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php');exit; } 

//дефинирање наслов
$title = 'Профил';

//хедер
require('layout/header.php'); 

?>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-   3">

            <h2>Добредојдовте: <?php echo $_SESSION['Fname']; ?> <?php echo     $_SESSION['Lname']; ?></h2>
            <p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>
            <p><a href='Update.php'>Update</a></p>
            <hr>

    </div>
</div>


</div>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset- 3">
        <form role="form" method="post" action="page_to_process.php"  autocomplete="off">
            <h3>Предмети</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <select required name="predmet1" id="predmet1" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="" class="placeholder" style="display: none;">Предмет1</option>  
                    <option value="Алгоритми и структури на податоци">Алгоритми и структури на податоци</option>  
                    <option value="Конечна Математика">Конечна Математика</option>  
                    <option value="Софтверско инженерство">Софтверско инженерство</option>
                    <option value="Веб програмирање">Веб програмирање</option>
                    <option value="Мултимедиски мрежи">Мултимедиски мрежи</option>
                    <option value="Принципи на мултимедиски системи">Принципи на мултимедиски системи</option>
                    <option value="Проектирање и развој на инф. системи">Проектирање и развој на инф. системи</option>
                    <option value="Инженерска технологија">Инженерска технологија</option>
                </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <select name="predmet2" id="predmet2" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="" class="placeholder" style="display: none;">Предмет2</option>  
                    <option value="Алгоритми и структури на податоци">Алгоритми и структури на податоци</option>  
                    <option value="Конечна Математика">Конечна Математика</option>  
                    <option value="Софтверско инженерство">Софтверско инженерство</option>
                    <option value="Веб програмирање">Веб програмирање</option>
                    <option value="Мултимедиски мрежи">Мултимедиски мрежи</option>
                    <option value="Принципи на мултимедиски системи">Принципи на мултимедиски системи</option>
                    <option value="Проектирање и развој на инф. системи">Проектирање и развој на инф. системи</option>
                    <option value="Инженерска технологија">Инженерска технологија</option>
                </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <select name="predmet3" id="predmet3" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="" class="placeholder" style="display: none;">Предмет3</option>  
                    <option value="Алгоритми и структури на податоци">Алгоритми и структури на податоци</option>  
                    <option value="Конечна Математика">Конечна Математика</option>  
                    <option value="Софтверско инженерство">Софтверско инженерство</option>
                    <option value="Веб програмирање">Веб програмирање</option>
                    <option value="Мултимедиски мрежи">Мултимедиски мрежи</option>
                    <option value="Принципи на мултимедиски системи">Принципи на мултимедиски системи</option>
                    <option value="Проектирање и развој на инф. системи">Проектирање и развој на инф. системи</option>
                    <option value="Инженерска технологија">Инженерска технологија</option>
                </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                <select name="predmet4" id="predmet4" class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="" class="placeholder" style="display: none;">Предмет4</option>  
                    <option value="Алгоритми и структури на податоци">Алгоритми и структури на податоци</option>  
                    <option value="Конечна Математика">Конечна Математика</option>  
                    <option value="Софтверско инженерство">Софтверско инженерство</option>
                    <option value="Веб програмирање">Веб програмирање</option>
                    <option value="Мултимедиски мрежи">Мултимедиски мрежи</option>
                    <option value="Принципи на мултимедиски системи">Принципи на мултимедиски системи</option>
                    <option value="Проектирање и развој на инф. системи">Проектирање и развој на инф. системи</option>
                    <option value="Инженерска технологија">Инженерска технологија</option>
                </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Зачувај" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

<?php 
//футер
require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [mysql_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) inside function `Conect()` (Co**n**nect, by the way)? Also, you may have a typo in the query in table name or column name.

And you should close tag `<table>` inside `if` statement

P.S. I don't have enought reputation to comment, so I wrote here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is an SQL and/or variable declaration error. The actual code appears to check out by sight, with the exceptions here.